# How can I know if a grouped products contains any MAP products?

Tags: product, price, magento-1, grouped-products

Basically I need to know if a grouped product contains any MAP sub product.

Is it possible to get this information without loading all product associated to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
You need to check if any of the Grouped Product has a MAP set?
You don't want to load all the product's because that can be slow.

The simplest suggestion I have is to gather all the Id's with

```
$ids = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProductIds($product);
```

Then you can use

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

Put it together. `'attribute_code'` => needed Attribute's code  **&&** `$storeId`

```
$ids = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProductIds($product);
foreach($ids as $id){
     $wantedAttribute = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($id, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
     if(SOME_CHECK){
         DOSOMETHING;
     }
}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try and I will back by tomorrow with vote :) Thanks

Comment: works like a charm, I just needed to change 'attribute_code' with the right value

Comment: Your Welcome,
Adding in a note to reflect the need to enter your values